# Swift Tuples in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an array of tuples I would like to save.
I found some doc about arrays in Core Data but didn't find any information about tuples. Is it possible to save tuples in Core Data or do I have to use a relationship like for arrays?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't save tupples in core data. Instead you can create `NSManagedObject` subclass and save it.

Comment: you mean as a transformable?

Comment: No not transformable. Just create class. For instance if you have tupple (name: String, age:Int) create model object from it.

Comment: I don't really see your point. You mean to create an object like a structure with inside only on tuple (or a list of tuples)? Cause in that case I can't sort my results based on this object, can I?

Comment: I'd expect that creating an entity specifically to represent the tuple format you've built is the way to go - and then either translate it back and forth from tuples or just stop using tuples for stored data.